# how to set google maps to 100% height in ngMap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, ng-map

Hey I am using [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) in order to display google map components.
Now for a very basic example, I am using bootstrap and try to put the google map on half of the screen,therefore I give it col-lg-6.

But apparently I get always the same height which is 300px.
I want the google map component to be in height of 100% and not a fixed height(which isn't responsive at all).
This is the code which I am talking about:

Here is a plunker of the problem:http://plnkr.co/edit/BQgMe5EQiFBmojgx45t5?p=preview

```js
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
  app.controller('EventSimpleCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var marker, map;
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
      map = evtMap;
      marker = map.markers[0];
    });
    $scope.centerChanged = function(event) {
      $timeout(function() {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      }, 3000);
    }
    $scope.click = function(event) {
      map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }
  }]);
```

```css
.map .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="EventSimpleCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!--<div class="panel panel-primary map">-->
        <!--  <div class="panel-heading">Test</div>-->
        <!--  <div class="panel-body">-->
        <!--    <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">-->
        <!--      <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>-->
        <!--    </map>-->
        <!--  </div>-->
        <!--</div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">
          <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please help me .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. A problem = a solution.

css :

```
.map{width:100%;} .panel-body {width:100%;}
```

html :

```
  <div ng-controller="EventSimpleCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!--<div class="panel panel-primary map">-->
    <!--  <div class="panel-heading">Test</div>-->
    <!--  <div class="panel-body">-->
    <!--    <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">-->
    <!--      <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>-->
    <!--    </map>-->
    <!--  </div>-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">
      <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>
    </map>
          </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I hope I answered your question. I test it on your Plunker link and it's OK.

Comment: why width, I asked for height not width

Comment: please give me a jsfiddle or a plunker, your solution doesn't work

Comment: this isn't 100% height but rather giving it a fixed height which isn't good from responsive issues.